# ReactJS + Nginx 404 Not Found

Tags: reactjs, nginx, nginx-config

After coding my first website on React, I want to host it on a raspberry pi using nginx.

I have checked website is ok by `npm start`:

I then built it to create static files using `npm run build` to create the following files in `~/Documents/myWebsite1/build`:

```
asset-manifest.json  css  favicon.ico  files  images  index.html  js  manifest.json  resumeData.json  robots.txt  static
```

After this I installed nginx, deleted `default` in both `/etc/nginx/sites-available` and `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled` then added the following file in `/etc/nginx/sites-available`:

```
server {
    listen  80;
    server_name     localhost;

    root    ~/Documents/myWebsite1/build;
    index index.html index.htm;

    location / {
            try_files $uri /index.html =404;
    }}
```

`nginx -t` confirms syntax is ok.

`nginx -T` confirms only this server block is running.

When I go to my IP address, the page just reads `404 Not Found`.

I have checked the logs using `sudo tail -n 20 /var/log/nginx/error.log` which return:

`2022/01/10 18:01:25 [notice] 15929#15929: signal process started`

Any ideas as to what I might be doing wrong?
Cheers,
Will

Answer (score 0):

Nginx was trying to access the directory ~/Documents/myWebsite1/build but ~ is only a shell shortcut. Changing to an absolute path fixed it right away :)